# Unable to Run Query with Cascade after Version upgrade from 20.07.2 to 20.07.3

Tags: database, graphql, distributed, distributed-system, dgraph

We are new to the dgraph database.
After Upgrading the server we are unable to run the below query with the cascade option

```
`query get_tenantlevel_data($tenantuid:string){
get_tenantlevel_data(func: type(cpc.mst.tenantlevels))
@filter(eq(active,true))
@cascade(hasTenant)
{ uid
hasTenant  
hasTenant@filter(uid($tenantuid))
}
}`
```

"errors": [ { "message": "line 4 column 15: Malformed Query. Missing {. Got (",
"extensions": { "code": "ErrorInvalidRequest"}}]
Earlier version 20.07.2 we are able to run the query and able to get the output. After upgrading to v20.07.3 we are getting the above error. We have read the release notes and could found anything relevant. Can anyone help with this to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that the query you are trying to run is not compatible with the new version of the database. In this case, you may need to modify the query to make it compatible with the new version.

Another possibility is that there is a bug in the new version of the database that is causing the query to fail. In this case, contact the database vendor or report the issue on the database's support forum to see if there is a known work around or if the issue will be fixed in a future update.

It is also possible that there is a problem with the database itself, such as corruption or incorrect configuration. In this case, you may need to restore the database from a backup.

Good luck!!